# Conditional formating - icons based on a value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to use the conditional formatting with the icons based on the value. I just want to compare Cell A to Cell B and show the icon based on the values. However, there is only the option of `>=`, `>` and `<`. I would like the option of checking the exact value, `=`.

My desired output is this:

- Cell A = Cell B -> Green icon
- Cell A > Cell B -> Red icon
- Cell A < Cell B -> Yellow icon

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Can you maybe use a third col: `=IF(A1 = B1, 1, IF(A1 > B1, -1, 0))`, so that it is _A=B =>_ **1**, _A>B_ => **-1**, _A<B_ => **0** and then use _Conditional Formatting_ on that column?

Comment: you write "however, there is only the option of ..." Where exactly do you see that option? What exactly do you have selected and what command do you click ??? We can't see your screen, so please specify EXACTLY what command you use or what Icon you click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do it, is to use the function `=SIGN(A1-B1)`, for instance in cell `C1`, and then add a conditional formatting on cell `C1` with the values `-1`, `0` and `1`.

The `SIGN` function returns:

- `1` if the argument is positive
- `-1` if the argument is negative
- `0` if the argument equals zero

By using the difference of `A1` and `B1` as the argument, you will know whether A is >, < or = to B.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare two different cells with conditional formatting, you can't use icon sets. Icon sets only take into account the cell that the value is in. Icon sets also set the icon based on a reference framework of tiered thresholds for the different icon colors. The icon is assigned for a match within a band of values, never a perfect match. Therefore you won't see the `=` option in an icon set rule definition.

You will need to create a helper column with a formula that does the evaluation and then you can format the helper column with an icon set.